# What viewers can display images in folders on a map like digiKam?

Tags: images, maps, image-viewer

I love **digiKam**'s feature of displaying my photos as pins on google-earth or similar maps, but I'm looking for other software with similar features, for digiKam's interface is kind of sluggish on such a large image-base.

So, what I need:

- A **photo organizer** or **image viewer**
- Must be able to put markers for photos with geotags on a navigable map.
- **Windows 10** compatible
- $30 or less
- *Bonus*: free
- *Bonus*: can set geotags itself on images that are missing the tag.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks. I've added the not-so-many requirements.

Comment: Thanks Fernando! Afraid I have to repeat myself nevertheless, quoting: *What OS shall the program run on? What is your price limit if it comes to paid software?* ;)